# Disable Submit button until fields have text?

Tags: html

So I have a form with two fields, one of these fields needs to have information in to successfully display the next page. How would I disable the submit button until that field has some text in it?

Here's the HTML Code;

```
    <div id="content">

    <form action="avatarquery.php" method="POST" id="login-form">

        <fieldset>

            <p>
                <label for="login-username">Server Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="login-username" name="name" class="round full-width-input" autofocus />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="login-password">Server IP:</label>
                <input type="text" id="login-password" name="ip" class="round full-width-input" />
            </p>

            <input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" type="submit" id="register" />


        </fieldset>

        <br/><div class="information-box round">Please Note: Some servers may not work due to their Configs not having Query Enabled.</div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript to have the submit button 'be enabled'. However, HTML5 introduced the `required` attribute which may help you.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the HTML5 Required :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that has to be done using HTML, then in HTML5, you can use

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Otherwise in JavaScript, you can try setting an attribute to the input button.

Until the value is "", you can set the attribute

```
<input type="submit" disabled />
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the HTML5 Function :)